# Sharing JSPs between EARs

Tags: java, jsp, struts, tiles, ear

Is it possible to share JSPs between EARs, similar to the way that we can share Java files between EARs by using .jar files?

I have a large J2EE app on JBoss with many different EARs, and they all should have the same header, footer, etc... I would rather not copy and paste these files a dozen times whenever a change needs to be made.

Comment: this can be achieved using velocity templace engine, by loading template from remote url (is supported by velocity out of the box) - maby this point you to something familiar for jsp

Comment: @inquisitor unfortunately there are thousands of JSPs, so porting to a different technology isn't feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Tag files can be packaged in a jar.

They are JSP files with a ".tag" extension. They can be parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried but logically speaking you can very well do it by putting all your JSP's into a common folder

Answer (score 0):

I think of it as accessing a different servlet context from the one you are in.  Something like

```
Enterprise.ear
  WAR1 /somewhere
  WAR2 /somewhereElse
  WAR3 /shared
```

Assuming a JSP in WAR1 bound to /somewhere:

Reference the shared context with the optional 'context' attribute of the c:import tag (Standard JSTL tag).  By default c:import uses the context it is in, which in war1 is /somewhwere.

```
<c:import url="/header.jsp"  context="/shared"/>
```

There are probably other ways... Perhaps just ignore your ear and just go with a full http request:

```
<c:import url="http://www.somewhere.com/header.jsp"/>
```

I'm not certain on the syntax of the context attribute on the c:import tag.  But I believe that is the correct syntax (with the slash verse without, it might not matter).

Comment: This is close, but I need the JSP before it's been rendered. For example, one of the files is the template for my Struts Tiles definition.

Answer (score 0):

Use sitemesh. 
There is no need to change anything in the existing application. Create a fresh war with sitemesh. It can decorate content from multiple urls dynamically.

http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/use_sitemesh_to_decorate_multiple

--Kiran.kumar